# How to use Singleton class injected by .NET MVC Ninject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I have some problem with InSingletonScope().

My interface:

```
public interface ISettingsManager
    {
        ApplicationSettings Application { get; }
    }
```

and my class:

```
public class SettingsManager : ISettingsManager
    {
        private readonly IConfigurationService _configurationService;

        private readonly Lazy<ApplicationSettings> _applicationSettings;
        public ApplicationSettings Application { get { return _applicationSettings.Value; } }

        private SettingsManager(IConfigurationService context)
        {
             _configurationService = context;

            _applicationSettings = new Lazy<ApplicationSettings>(() => new ApplicationSettings(context));
        }
}
```

and binding looks like this:

```
kernel.Bind<ISettingsManager>().To<SettingsManager>().InSingletonScope();
```

What do you think about this approach?

For example, in HomeControler, when I'm add:

```
[Inject]
SettingsManager _settingsManager;
```

the `_settingsManager` is always null.

How I can use SettingsManager singleton in another project? I always get null.

Answer (score 0):

> What do you think about this approach?

InSingletonScope() - Only a single instance of the type will be created, and the same instance will be returned for each subsequent request. The dependency will have same scope as of Kernel i.e. Disposed when the Kernel is Disposed.

Read about object scopes [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes).

```
[Inject]
SettingsManager _settingsManager;
```

What are you trying to do here? Field injection?

I do not think it is supported. Copied following from official page:

> Field Injection is a bad practice, and got cut for minimization as
>   part of the rewrite between v1 and v2. There is no field injection in
>   Ninject v2.

You can use Property or Constructor injection instead.

**Property Injection:**

```
[Inject]
public ISettingsManager SettingsManager { private get; set; }
```

**Constructor Injection:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{    
    readonly ISettingsManager settingsManager;

    public HomeController(ISettingsManager settingsManager )
    {
        if(settingsManager == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("settingsManager is null");

        this.settingsManager = settingsManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how it works, but I want to ask if my implementation is consistent with this. 
And I want to make Property injection (not Filed), but I always get null.

Comment: @user3146344 - consistent with this? Please check my answer and the link provided, hopefully it will help.

Comment: I try property injection and I still get: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Web.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

Comment: That means you do not have dependency code setup properly. If you debug does breakpoint hit the binding call?

Comment: Yes. In debug I can see that the call hit: kernel.Bind<ISettingsManager>().To<SettingsManager>().InSingletonScope();

Comment: So if you remove InSingletonScope() then does the property or ctor injection works?

Comment: Unfortunately not. After removal is still the same. The problem exists when I add seconde one property injection to Home Controller. Without this everything works well.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and clearly mention these observations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your _settingsManager to have a type of ISettingsManager instead of SettingsManager.

(You're binding ISettingsManager to SettingsManager. This means when Ninject sees a dependency on ISettingsManager it will inject a SettingsManager. If something is directly declared as SettingsManager it won't do anything)

Comment: Also, as the other answer says, you can't directly inject to a field. I'd recommend changing to Constructor injection instead.

Comment: I added constructor injection is HomeController and I have: public HomeController(IProductService context, ISettingsManager settingsManager) , but I get error: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Web.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

I want to use my Singleton many times in my app. That's why I have to do constructor injection in each class?