# Error during InSingletonScope() with Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I have some problem with InSingletonScope().

My interface:

```
public interface ISettingsManager
    {
        ApplicationSettings Application { get; }
    }
```

and my class:

```
public class SettingsManager : ISettingsManager
    {
        private readonly IConfigurationService _configurationService;

        private readonly Lazy<ApplicationSettings> _applicationSettings;
        public ApplicationSettings Application { get { return _applicationSettings.Value; } }

        private SettingsManager(IConfigurationService context)
        {
             _configurationService = context;

            _applicationSettings = new Lazy<ApplicationSettings>(() => new ApplicationSettings(context));
        }
}
```

and standard binding in NinjectWebCommon looks like this:

```
kernel.Bind<ISettingsManager>().To<SettingsManager>().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<IConfigurationService >().To<ConfigurationService>().InRequestScope();
```

And when I use constructor injection or property injection in HomeController:

```
    [Inject]
    public ISettingsManager SettingsManager { private get;}
```

Then I get an error:

```
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Web.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
```

Where is the problem? What is wrong with my Singleton?

I use in my project dependency injection and when I inject one interface in constructor, everything work fine. When I add ISettingsManagers I have many problems.

Comment: 1) Have you made sure your controllers are being added to the container, i.e. have you specified `GlobalConfiguration.DependencyResolver`, 2) Why do you have property injection AND constructor injection on the same controller - or are you passing in some random arguments to your constructor.

Comment: 1) How I can specify `GlobalConfiguration.DependencyResolver` ? I use only standard NinjectWebCommon.
2) In my Home Controller I have some service injection (InRequestScope) and this is working fine. When I add ISettingsManager in second parameter in Home Controller (or in the property injection) I always get the error with parameterless public constructor

Comment: show your `NinjectWebCommon` unless it looks like this [link](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/blob/master/src/SampleApplication/App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs). Are you in WebApi or MVC or both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Singleton class injected by .NET MVC Ninject?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133557/how-to-use-singleton-class-injected-by-net-mvc-ninject)

Comment: @RuaidhriPrimrose the answer to that question is to bind it to an interface - this one already is....

Comment: @CallumLinington my `NinjectWebCommon` looks the same like in your link. I use only MVC.

Comment: read this [article](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/19/adding-ninject-to-web-api/#using-ninject-to-resolve-the-repository-dependency), the steps are: 1) create `NinjectDependencyResolver`, 2) Hook it up in the `global.asax` or something

Comment: @CallumLinington I added `NinjectDependencyResolver` and hooked it up in the global.asax, but I still get the same problem. When I remove ISettingsManager injection, everything work good. What could be wrong with InSingletonScope?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `InSingletonScope` it will be your code unfortunately :(. could you show the global.asax

Comment: Also, have you registered absolutely everything else that needs to be register.... this also causes this issue!

Answer (score 1):

I know what was wrong. The private constructor was the main problem. When I change it to:

`public SettingsManager(IConfigurationService context)`

then it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The Error it self says its the home controller that needs to be parameterless, however if ninject is setup correctly that is not true, and the bug can be nested down to a single class that does not have the bindings needed.

However, there is one thing that might go wrong in what you show here.

Your configuration is in request scope and your settings is in singleton scope.

This means it might run fine the first time, however in the second attempt, its a new request and the configuration, could be disposed inside your singleton settings, and would proberbly break something.